# Wrong version on System.Data.SqlClient referenced by Runtime

Tags: c#, dll

I have a class library I am writing in Visual Studio 2017 using .NET Standard 2.0. I have added System.Data.SqlClient v4.6.0 as Dependency.

When running the application that seeks to load the DLL at runtime it complains it can't find version 4.5.0.   If I replace the dependency version with Version V4.5.0 (using NuGet) and then run again, it complains it can't find versions 4.4.0.

e.g. with version V4.6.0 as a dependency the error message is :

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How many projects do you have in your solution? Does any other project had a diferente version?

Comment: 3 projects - 2 class libraries and a command line executable to call the DLLs. Only one class library references the SqlClient. (thanks for checking)